# After changing path using RouteConfig old path is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a C# ASP.NET MVC project with Entity Framework.

I am trying to change the url path using `RouteConfig.cs`

First the code looked like this

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I wanted to chenge the url `localhost/Customer/Index` to `localhost/Index`

So I added this line of code and it worked

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "customer",
    url: "customer",
    defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index"}
);
```

Next I tried changing `localhost/Customer/Details/2` to `localhost/CustomerName/2`.

```
// CustomerName varies with each customer
```

so I added this

```
 routes.MapRoute(
     name: "customerDetail",
     url: "customer/{name}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now customer details page loads correctly.

But loading Index page using this path `localhost/Customer/Index` causes an error, while `localhost/Customer` causes no error. Why this is happening?

***EDIT***

This is how my `RouteConfig` looks like

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "customer",
            url: "customer",
            defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index"}
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "customerDetail",
            url: "customer/{name}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Order of how you add routes is important. Show the RouteConfig as it currently is after you made your changes. Chances are you have a route conflict.

Comment: Seems that you have wrong route order defined in `RouteConfig` there. The most specific routes should be on top of broader/default routes.

Comment: Your 2nd route does not generate `localhost/Index` - it generates `localhost/customer`

Comment: And only the last parameter can be marked `UrlParameter.Optional`

Comment: Updated my question with current rout config

Comment: `localhost/Customer/Index` matches the `customerDetail` route (and passes "Index" to the `id` parameter)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i understand that  it generates `localhost/customer`. But when i load the page locally from visual studio the path will be `localhost/Customer/Index` thats when i get error

Comment: @ashik What is the error you are getting. Can you post may be a screen shot of the error?

Comment: Try defining a second route: `routes.MapRoute(name: "customerWithIndex" ,  url: "customer/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index"}
        );`

Comment: `localhost/Customer/Index` matches second route & routes to something like `localhost/Customer/Details/Index`. If the passed argument `Index` not exist on `Details` action method, it may throwing error. The route should be defined as `/customer/{action}/{id}` (id is optional).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found an answer.

> As @StephenMuecke commented
>
> > `localhost/Customer/Index` matches the `customerDetail` route (and passes `"Index"` to the id parameter)

So I rechecked my code and found that the `id` field in `localhost/Customer/Details/2` is not optional and i accidently defined it as optional, `id = UrlParameter.Optional`.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "customerDetail",
        url: "customer/{name}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Details", name = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Full RoutConfig code:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "customer",
            url: "customer",
            defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index"}
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "customerDetail",
            url: "customer/{name}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Details",name = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Remove `id` as `UrlParameter.Optional` from existing code

```
public class RouteConfig
{
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
   {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "customer",
        url: "customer",
        defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index"}
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "customerDetail",
        url: "customer/{name}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Details", name = UrlParameter.Optional } // Removed idas optional from existing code
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

   }
}
```